# when I use pygame to load an picture, but an error has occured

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

This is my code:

```
import pygame
class Ship():
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')

my_ship = Ship
print(my_ship.image)
AttributeError: type object 'Ship' has no attribute 'image'
```

I use pycharm6 and python3.6. I'm a beginner in python, hope someone can help me.

Comment: We need a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And post the full traceback (error message).

Comment: Sorry, I have re-modified the format.

Comment: You should learn Python more, after that you can understand that you need to instantiate instance of Ship.

Answer (score 2):

`my_ship = Ship`

On its own, this is not loading the variables, just setting it a copy of the actual class Ship. Change this to `my_ship = Ship()`, and it will actually make it an instance of the Ship class, so the `self.image` variable will be loaded as well.